# Why return type can influence access to methods of the returned object?

Tags: java

Could you help me to understand the following code? I'm puzzled by the behavior of private inner classes a bit. I stumbled upon this while reading Core Java. I have a private inner class called `Iterator`.

```java
private class Iterator implements java.util.Iterator<String> {
    private Node currentNode = head;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return currentNode != null && currentNode.next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        String value = currentNode.value;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        return value;
    }
}
```

In the outer class, I can implement retrieving the Iterator in one of the following ways:

Number one:

```java
public java.util.Iterator<String> getIterator() {
    return new Iterator();
}
```

Number two:

```java
public Iterator getIterator() {
    return new Iterator();
}
```

Then, if in any other class, I call `getIterator()`, if it's the version that returns `java.util.Iterator`, I can call the next() method. If the `getIterator()` returns Iterator (the inner class directly) I can't access `next()`.

Could you help me understand this behavior? Why does returning the private class iterator as the `java.util.Iterator` interface makes the methods accessible?

Comment: Because java.util.Iterator is public, and you just return an implementation of that interface.